# Multiple unique in mysql not supporting NULL

Tags: mysql, unique

```
ALTER TABLE admins ADD CONSTRAINT uc_EmailandDeleted_at UNIQUE (email,deleted_at);
```

I have changed my table to work as this:

```
ID  EMAIL                  DELETED_AT  
1.  user@example.com          NULL             <- accept  
2.  user@example.com          NULL             <- reject because of uniqueness.
```

But Its not working as I wish. If i gave two identical dates to

```
deleted_at
```

It is generating error as I expect. But not for NULL values. Any idea?

NB: I can't change the behaviors of `deleted_at` column because I am using acts_as_paranoid. So I have to keep `deleted_at` field to be NULL or any date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply
>   to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a
>   UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain
>   NULL.

The above excerpt from MySQL 5.0. MySQL dropped the BDB storage engine in 5.1.12.
So now from the latest [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html):

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

Comment: So , I want to change the behavior of deleted_at to a boolean value to make this work, rite?? any way thanks..

Comment: FYI, changed in 5.5 "For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL."